# How to predict using Keras?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, keras

I'm using model.predict() to make predictions batch by batch.

By doing so, I find that Keras seems to normalize the input on a batch basis which means if I combine the results, they will become meaningless because they are not normalized together and the probabilities vary a lot from batch to batch.

So what should I do to tackle this? Loading all the data into one batch is not an option as the dataset is too large. Should I pass in one sample per time at the cost of performance?

Comment: I am facing the same problem. Have you found out any solution for that? If yes please share it.

Comment: In what way do you observe that Keras normalizes the input on a batch basis?

Comment: What is the memory size of your data till which you can safely perform the training ? I use a 8GB RAM system and I see that when my input data size plus output data size, for regression problem, approaches around 7.5 GB I get a memory error during training ?

Comment: @AvijitDasgupta No I didn't. I switched my codebase to TF instead...

Comment: @1'' I printed the prediction for the same input multiple times and found them different, though it might not affect the predicted class.

Comment: @tauseef_CuriousGuy If your train data is too big for your memory, try loading a batch each time instead of loading them all into the memory, though this way you cannot randomize through the whole dataset.